# Is there is any possible ways to save network calls locally from network tab in Chrome Developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was trying to save the network calls that are available on the Network tab of Chrome Developer tools.

The problem is, i can able to view the network calls along with response time after my individual request,but i could not save it..so kindly suggest me that Is there is any possible way to save the network calls locally from the network tab of Google chrome - Developer tools

Answer (score 4):

First, right click anywhere in the Network Panel and select "Save as HAR with content." This will save the entire network log into a single file.

Now, find a HAR viewer such as [chromeHAR](http://ericduran.github.io/chromeHAR/). Open the HAR up within a viewer program to see the data. Yes, chromeHAR uses a very old interface, but is still very usable to get a quick look at the data.

Remember that the HAR file is a simple JSON structure. It should be pretty easy if needed to build your own tool to analyze the data or display it however you wish.

Saving the HAR:
[image: save har]

Viewing the HAR online:
[image: online har view]

Comment: Hi Garbee, is there any other possible ways to save the network call via selenium webdriver?
i actually feeling that extracting required data from HAR format is quite difficult

Comment: Might be worth asking another question on how to extract the data you want. That kind of information could be helpful to many people trying to figure it out. On using it with Selenium WebDriver, that also seems to warrant another question, since it isn't related to the primary question asked here.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, will try to post these as separate question..if found any answers,kindly do let me know

Answer (score 1):

Select all with Ctrl - A, then right click and "Save as HAR with content". It will be saved in a .har file.
You can open this with several tools. Online there is the [Google HAR Analyzer](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer/). You can find other tools too.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.Extracting my required data from har format is more complex.Is there is any other way to extract the Network tab as it is..which is available on Developer tools

Comment: You could also try to just select all and then drag and drop into excel, but I'm not sure how well structured it will be.

Comment: As of now, i can able to access the developer tool via Selenium Webdriver. But, i could n't access the Network tab.For that i need the xpath of developer tool to proceed further